# How to get daily APR from APY

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to calculate the daily APR from an APY (Annual Percentage Yield) rate.

I know the APY formula is:

$$\mathrm{APY} = \left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n - 1,$$

which is for example in my case

$$20 = \left(1 + \frac{r}{365.25}\right)^{365.25} - 1.$$

My maths skills are far behind me, how can I calculate $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{alignat}{2}
20 &= \left(1 + \frac{r}{365.25}\right)^{365.25} - 1 &\\
21 &=\left(1 + \frac{r}{365.25}\right)^{365.25} &\text{(add $1$ to each side)}\\ 
21^{1/365.25}&=1 + \frac{r}{365.25}  &\text{(raise each side to the $1/365.25$ power)}\\
21^{1/365.25} - 1 &=\frac{r}{365.25}  &\text{(subtract $1$ from each side)}\\
365.25\left(21^{1/365.25} - 1\right) &= r  &\text{(multiply each side by $365.25$)}
\end{alignat}

So, we arrive at $$r = 365.25\left(21^{1/365.25} - 1\right) \approx 3.057.$$

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your answer

Comment: Glad I could help, if that answers your question feel free to 'accept' it.